# Authenticating custom field on login

Tags: plugins, plugin-gravity-forms

How do I get a custom field to be authenticated? I am storing `player_id` as user meta in the `user_meta` table, but how can I have my login check the field? I'm using Gravity Forms to create my login, but I need be able to check `player_id` against the user id.

For example, at present I am using a front-end form to log in, but there is no authentication against `player_id`. I need be able to check `player_id` in `user_meta` to see if it matches the one the user has keyed in.

Comment: What have you tried? Please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/206035/edit) to include the relevant code snippet(s).

Comment: If their is another stack please let me no where i can ask for advice I didnt relise had to share code i am asking for advice

Comment: The intent on WPSE is to assist with specific questions or problems with code. Are you using a plugin? If so, check that plugin's support streams. If you're writing a custom plugin, then adding your code to the question will help us figure out what issues you may be having. See [the help](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for details on how to get the most out of WPSE.